# How to Delete child without deleting parent in one-to-one bidirectional mapping?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I have one-to-one mapping on both parent & child side, I want to delete only child without deleting the parent, parent_id is set to not null so that we don't end up with null values.
When I try to delete I get no error, and no records of child are deleted either

Can someone help me?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS child
(
    id                                      bigint         NOT NULL,
    parent_id                               bigint         NOT NULL,
    
    CONSTRAINT child_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT parent_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent (id),
);


@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@TypeDefs({@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)})
public class Parent {

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "intelligentGroup")
  private Child child;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@Immutable
public class Child {

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Parent parent;

}

childRepo.delete(child);
```

I also tried to set child as null and then delete, but it violates not-null  constraint

Comment: Remove the Immutable annotation.

Comment: Remove cascadetype all if you don't want parent to be deleted.

Comment: @Mar-Z, Child has a foreign key reference to parent, will that delete as foreign key is still not detached

Comment: @Mar-Z I tried by removing cascadeType, but still it did not delete row